# PostgreSQL: get all rows that contain an uppercase letter

Tags: sql, database, string, postgresql, where-clause

How can I do the following stmt:

```sql
select * from table
where column has any uppercase letters; <-- how to write this
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can filter with a regex:

```
select * 
from mytable
where mycolumn ~ '[A-Z]'
```

Another approach is string comparison:

```
select * 
from mytable
where lower(mycolumn) <> mycolumn
```

Comment: perfect, exactly what I am looking for, Thank you!

Comment: In regex example pattern must have single quotes: mycolumn ~ '[A-Z]'